# What is member interpretation in Range-based for loop (since C++11)?

Tags: c++, c++11, range-based-loop

I read [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for a range-based `for` loop:

> The member interpretation is used if the range type has a member named begin and a member named end. This is done regardless of whether the member is a type, data member, function, or enumerator, and regardless of its accessibility. Thus a class like `class meow { enum { begin = 1, end = 2}; /* rest of class */ };` cannot be used with the range-based for loop even if the namespace-scope begin/end functions are present.

I do not understand this paragraph. What does the member interpretation do so as to forbid the example class being used with the range-based for loop?

Comment: Like the quote says, it'll find the names `begin` and `end` inside `meow` and since those aren't functions that return iterators, the range based for loop can't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "member interpretation" refers to `begin_expr` and `end_expr` using members of the iterated type in contrast to using plain offsets for arrays or `begin` and `end` free functions.

The array interpretation is off the table, because it is only used for arrays. Next consider that there is [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and `std::end`:

> Custom overloads of begin may be provided for classes and enumerations that do not expose a suitable begin() member function, yet can be iterated.

Now consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class meow { 
    enum { begin = 1, end = 2}; 
    public:
    std::vector<int> data;
};

// non-const iterators
auto begin(meow& m){ return m.data.begin(); }
auto end(meow& m) { return m.data.end(); }
// const iterators
auto begin(const meow& m){ return m.data.begin(); }
auto end(const meow& m) { return m.data.end(); }

int main() {
    meow m;
    for (const auto& e : m) {}
}
```

We want to iterate the `meow`s `data`. But it does not work. The member interpratation is choosen, even though `meow::begin` and `mewo::end` are private and the `begin` and `end` functions could be used. Hence the error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:26: error: 'meow::<unnamed enum> begin' is private within this context
     for (const auto& e : m) {}
                          ^
<source>:5:12: note: declared private here
     enum { begin = 1, end = 2};
            ^~~~~
<source>:17:26: error: 'begin' cannot be used as a function
     for (const auto& e : m) {}
                          ^
<source>:17:26: error: 'meow::<unnamed enum> end' is private within this context
<source>:5:23: note: declared private here
     enum { begin = 1, end = 2};
                       ^~~
<source>:17:26: error: 'end' cannot be used as a function
     for (const auto& e : m) {}
                          ^
```

The example works fine when we remove the private enum:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class meow { 
    //enum { begin = 1, end = 2}; 
    public:
    std::vector<int> data;
};

// non-const iterators
auto begin(meow& m){ return m.data.begin(); }
auto end(meow& m) { return m.data.end(); }
// const iterators
auto begin(const meow& m){ return m.data.begin(); }
auto end(const meow& m) { return m.data.end(); }

int main() {
    meow m;
    for (const auto& e : m) {}
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oE9seqb6d)